# $( elem ).attr("checked") giving opposite results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, debugging, checkbox

Clicking checkbox should give alert checked if checked and give alert not checked if not. Here is the code:

```
<input type = "checkbox" id = "all" value="all" /> MyCheckbox

 <script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {   
alert("checked");
}
else{
alert("not checked");
}
});
</script>
```

Initially checkbox is unchecked. As soon as I click it, debugger shows it checked value true. Now control should enter if{} block as its value is true but its entering in else{} block. (Am using breakpoints).

Why this is happening. Pls help am trying for hours.

Comment: You can also use `.prop()`. A good answer about the difference between `attr()` and `prop()` can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: How not? You can use `.prop("checked", true)` to check if the checkbox is checked. *EDIT*: Ok, the comment above was removed. This comment was aimed at the previous one...

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/prop/ There is even example on the page which shows difference between using of attr() and prop().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are checking `checked` attribute which is not going to be removed or added when checked status changes. This is a nuance you should be aware about properties and attributes. You need to compare `checked` *property* of the checkbox element, not attribute.

Also it's better to use `change` event handler (because you can check checkbox not only with mouse click but with keyboard too).

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        alert("checked");
    }
    else {
        alert("not checked");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "checkbox" id = "all" value="all" /> MyCheckbox
```

Comment: Thanks! And is (this.checked) same as $(this).prop("checked") or if ($(this).is(":checked")) ?

Comment: Yes, it's the same, just jQuery wrappers. I would go with native thing, shorter and clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This :

```
$(this).attr("checked") //in old versions of jquery this yield "checked" ,
```

Yields `undefined` which is a Falsy statement.

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set

You can either use :

```
if ($(this).is(":checked"))
```

or

```
$(this).prop("checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

As of **jQuery 1.6**, the *.attr()* method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the **checked, selected, or disabled state** of form elements, use the *.prop()* method.